# JQuery - Check if next element of DOM has some classname

Tags: jquery, dom

somethings
            

            
                somethings
            

             
                somethings
            

            
                somethings

i need a function that check the next element in the dom and get the classname.
For example, if i get sideline0, the function will return "trackon" (classname of the next element). If i get sideline1, it must return "sideone" and so on..

any idea? cheers

Comment: I can't see your code, can you try to edit and mark it as a code block so the HTML brackets aren't eaten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `next()` and `attr` like this:

```
alert($('selector').next().attr('class'));
```

Since you have not mentioned an event, here is sample code for click event of those divs (you can modify as per your needs):

```
$('.tlcontent > div').click(function(){
  alert($(this).next().attr('class'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

How 'bout:

```
var clz = $('#sideline0').next()[0].className;
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/esofu3 (in that example, I gave `next` the parameter "div" to say I only wanted to look at divs — handy if you want to skip chaff, but not necessary with your sample code).

That uses [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the next element, and then boring old JavaScript and DOM to get the reflected version of the `class` attribute. (Or you can use jQuery's `attr` to retrieve the class attribute instead if you prefer, as [babtek suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746059/jquery-check-if-next-element-of-dom-has-some-classname/3746077#3746077).)

Answer (score 2):

Using #sideline0 as the example element, this should get you the class value of the next DOM element:

```
$('#sideline0').next().attr('class')
```

Answer (score 1):

USE

```
$('#sideline0').next().attr('class');
```

here is a working example http://jsfiddle.net/yCqkC/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for your specific example because your code is hidden (put 4 spaces before each line so the software reads it as code).  However, in general, you can get the classname of the next DOM element as follows:

```
var className = $('#sideline0').next().attr('class');
```